# Better notifications for Private Messages / Mentions in Chatter?

Tags: chatter, notification

When someone sends me a private message or mentions me in some feed post, is there a way to configure Salesforce to show a notification on the top bar, without having to manually open the Chatter Feed or go to the  Chatter tab?

Maybe something like Facebook notifications:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The notifications will show up if you use Salesforce1, either the app on your mobile device or the browser app.

You can follow this article about how to enable Salesforce1 for your org:
http://jessealtman.com/2013/12/working-with-salesforce1-on-the-desktop/

To navigate to the Salesforce1 app in your browser, change the /home/home.jsp in your url to /one/one.app.

Comment: Yes, these are currently the only out-of-the-box options for getting notifications. They aren't available in the standard Salesforce web UI.